# Transfer data from old WD mirror to new Synology d220+

Tags: networking, hard-drive, wireless-networking, nas

I purchased a Synology D220+ NAS and equipped it with (2)-8tb hhds. Moving this data off the old Nas to the new will take time I know. My concern is ensuring the SAFE transfer, not the speed necessarily, however if both speed and accuracy are possible, I'm in!

So from the initial setup into a home network, using a router, switch,a PC running windows 10, and "just enough tech know-how to be dangerous", how do I set this up to transfer data one to the other.

Currently I have capability to see and access both devices on the PC, and have successfully moved test files. Can I utilize Ethernet cabling directly? If so, I'm just lost in all the settings and various scenarios that come into play.

If learning is the task at hand, I'll dig in! I need assistance in choosing the most prudent path! Thank you for your willingness and any help, I can help with gardening and electrical design, but like I sorta mentioned, the technology is just leaving me lost.

Comment: There's really not much to it. Copy (instead of move) everything you need from the old to the new. Once you're satisfied the copied files are fine you can then delete the original ones.

Comment: consider robust tools like rsync or robocopy, that are resumable, error checking, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use File Station on the Synology device (through the web browser interface) to log in to the old NAS: in File Station, use "Tools" -> "Mount remote folder" to connect. Then just copy the files, and you won't have to have another computer on during the copy.

Comment: agreed, either pull from the new nas, or push from the old one, using whatever built in protocols are available (ssh/sftp, SMB, remote mounts, etc). its best not to do a "triangular" copy where the copy command is running on a third system.